# Setting focus to the end of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, textarea

```
editor.focus();
```

Sets the focus fine in Chrome.
But in Firefox, the focus is set on the beginning on the line. I want it to be set on the end of the line. I tried this:

```
moveCaretToEnd(ed);

function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
      el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
      el.focus();
      var range = el.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(false);
      range.select();
    }
}
```

And stupid FF doesn't work again. The focus is gone.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle demo for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the following hack for firefox:

```
var value = editor.val();
editor.val("");
editor.focus();
editor.val(value);
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/p37ax/

Comment: Ha, I knew there had to be an easy way to do this.  Thanks for the great answer!